# Vuetify.js - dynamic card height animation

Tags: animation, vuejs2, css-transitions, vuetify.js

I'm having two paragraphs (one big and one small) inside a v-card which switches on button click. Is there a way to make the card animate as if it is expanding while switching. Here is how it looks

```
<v-card>

   <v-btn @click="show=!show" flat>show</v-btn>

   <v-card-text v-show="show">
      <!-- short paragraph -->
   </v-card-text>

   <v-card-text v-show="!show">
       <!-- long paragraph -->
   </v-card-text>

</v-card>
```

Assume `show` is a variable defined in vue object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `v-expand-transition` from Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/transitions#expand-transition.

Just use one `v-card-text` containing a `div` for each the short and the long paragraph and wrap each into `v-expand-transition`

```
    <v-card-text>
      <v-expand-transition>
        <div v-show="show">This is a short paragraph</div>
      </v-expand-transition>
      <v-expand-transition>
        <div v-show="!show">
          <p>A looooong</p>
          <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </v-expand-transition>
    </v-card-text>
```

Working example on Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-q46305305-4qq4940x5w